# Using nLog, is it possible to change the log level of a log entry with configuration

Tags: nlog

Is it possible to change log level of log entry **before** it is "written" in config?

Examples:

- A library logs certain events as `Warn` while we only want them logged at `Info`.
- We have fixed a bug and want to log certain log entries at `Info` or `Debug` until the next rollout.

I see that nLog could be able to filter and ignore messages using conditions like in the following config ([Filtering-log-messages](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages)):

```xml
<logger name="*" writeTo="file">
  <filters defaultAction="Log">
    <when condition="length('${message}') > 100" action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

However, I don't want to completely remove the log entries...

Is it possible to use something similar to change the entry's level from `Warn` to `Info`?  This would need to happen **before** targets as the targets may have rules based on the log level.

Comment: So your question is 'Can `logger.Warn("warning")` be routed as if it was written as `logger.Info("warning")`'?

Comment: Possibly you can use [Semi Dynamic Routing Rules](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules) but that would require adjustments in your code